# Getting "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" while executing PIG scripts from Java application

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-pig, heap-memory, hadoop2

I having a Java Swing application. Internally it is generating PIG scripts to convert xml data to structured data. I have written the logic in java to generate the PIG scripts.

My xml file is inside hdfs. **My application running fine when I am selecting xml file of size 56MB (156636 records)**. But as soon as I am selecting xml file more than this it is throwing `java.lang.Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

**Eclipse Console error snippet:**

```
16/03/04 20:52:47 INFO mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader: Current split being processed hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/hadoopqatstool/input/xml/Books_WS_MM_2.xml:0+109899360
16/03/04 20:52:47 INFO data.SchemaTupleBackend: Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
16/03/04 20:52:47 INFO mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map: Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: xmldata1[1,11],xmldata2[-1,-1],xmldata3[3,11],xmldata4[4,11],xmldata5[5,11],xmldata6[6,11],xmldata8[8,11],xmldata7[7,11],null[-1,-1] C:  R: 
16/03/04 20:52:49 INFO util.SpillableMemoryManager: first memory handler call - Collection threshold init = 85983232(83968K) used = 857675192(837573K) committed = 1172832256(1145344K) max = 1380974592(1348608K)
16/03/04 20:52:50 INFO util.SpillableMemoryManager: first memory handler call- Usage threshold init = 85983232(83968K) used = 1013180544(989434K) committed = 1172832256(1145344K) max = 1380974592(1348608K)
16/03/04 20:52:57 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
16/03/04 20:52:57 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1196112634_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:331)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:777)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.encode(Text.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.<init>(Text.java:88)
    at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader$XMLRecordReader.nextKeyValue(XMLLoader.java:207)
    at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader.getNext(XMLLoader.java:262)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader.nextKeyValue(PigRecordReader.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/03/04 20:52:58 WARN mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher: Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
16/03/04 20:52:58 INFO mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher: job job_local1196112634_0001 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
16/03/04 20:52:58 INFO mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher: 100% complete
16/03/04 20:52:58 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
16/03/04 20:52:58 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
16/03/04 20:52:58 ERROR mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil: 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
16/03/04 20:52:58 INFO mapreduce.SimplePigStats: Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.6.0   0.15.0  hduser  2016-03-04 20:52:46 2016-03-04 20:52:58 FILTER

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_local1196112634_0001    xmldata1,xmldata2,xmldata3,xmldata4,xmldata5,xmldata6,xmldata7,xmldata8 MAP_ONLY    Message: Job failed!    /user/hduser/hadoopqatstool/output/xml/2016-03-04T20_52_46,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/hadoopqatstool/input/xml/Books_WS_MM_2.xml"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "/user/hduser/hadoopqatstool/output/xml/2016-03-04T20_52_46"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_local1196112634_0001


16/03/04 20:52:58 INFO mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher: Failed!
```

I searched to solve this problem, I found that increasing the HADOOP_HEAP size can solve this problem inside hadoop-env.sh file. So I changed it accordingly.

**Part of my hadoop-env.sh (Before change)**

```
# The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
#export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=
#export HADOOP_NAMENODE_INIT_HEAPSIZE=""

export HADOOP_PORTMAP_OPTS="-Xmx512m $HADOOP_PORTMAP_OPTS"
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx512m $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
```

**I changed my hadoop-env.sh to this (After change)**

```
# The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=4096
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_INIT_HEAPSIZE="4096"

export HADOOP_PORTMAP_OPTS="-Xmx4096m $HADOOP_PORTMAP_OPTS"
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx4096m $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
```

But after doing these changes also I am getting the same out of memory error.

**One record of my XML data is like this. like wise I am having multiple records**

```
<book id="bk101">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>
   </book>
```

**My System details:**

1. Pseudo distributed single node hadoop physical machine.
2. hadoop version: Apache hadoop 2.6.0
3. pig version: 0.15.0
4. RAM: 8GB
5. OS: Ubuntu 14.04LTS
6. 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Check if you assigned more memory to the mapper and reducer 
(mapreduce.map.memory.mb, mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb) than the java.

Answer (score 0):

you are most likely exceeding the amount of memory given to the java process that is running your mapper/reducer. There are a lot of memory settings that you can tweak to get past this.  Here goes -

The following properties let you specify options to be passed to the JVMs running your tasks. These can be used with -Xmx to control heap available.

```
 mapreduce.map.java.opts

 mapreduce.reduce.java.opts
```

Note there is no direct Hadoop 2 equivalent for the first of these; the advice in the source code is to use the other two. mapred.child.java.opts is still supported (but is overridden by the other two more-specific settings if present).
Complementary to these, the following let you limit total memory (possibly virtual) available for your tasks - including heap, stack and class definitions:

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb  

mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
```

I suggest setting -Xmx to 75% of the memory.mb values.
In a YARN cluster, jobs must not use more memory than the server-side config yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb or they will be killed.
To check the defaults and precedence of these, see JobConf and MRJobConfig in the Hadoop source code.

Remember that your mapred-site.xml may provide defaults for these settings. This can be confusing - e.g. if your job sets mapred.child.java.opts programmatically, this would have no effect if mapred-site.xml sets mapreduce.map.java.opts or mapreduce.reduce.java.opts. You would need to set those properties in your job instead, to override the mapred-site.xml. Check your job's configuration page (search for 'xmx') to see what values have been applied and where they have come from.
ApplicationMaster memory

In a YARN cluster, you can use the following two properties to control the amount of memory available to your ApplicationMaster (to hold details of input splits, status of tasks, etc):

```
 yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts
 yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb
```

Again, you could set -Xmx (in the former) to 75% of the resource.mb value.
Other configurations

Set this to a low value (10) to force shuffle to happen on disk in the event that you hit an OutOfMemoryError at MapOutputCopier.shuffleInMemory

Answer (score 0):

As you changed hadoop-env.sh file.
Now you can change conf/mapred-site.xml

> mapred.child.java.opts =-Xmx4096M

then restart your Hadoop.

Ref : http://allthingshadoop.com/2010/04/28/map-reduce-tips-tricks-your-first-real-cluster/

Comment: I have changed my conf/mapred-site.xml also but still I am facing the same issue.